# What happens to the velocity of a radioactively decaying object?

Tags: momentum, mass, conservation-laws, velocity, radioactivity

Suppose that I have a lump of a radioactive material, like Uranium-235. I put it in an ideal box, which perfectly isolates the inside from the outside - no radiation escapes the box and the outer surface of the box does not change in any way. The box is thrown by an astronaut with velocity $v_0$. The mass of the box and the lump is $m_0$.

[image]

As time goes by, the radioactive material decays. After time $t$ has passed, the total mass of the box and the partially decayed lump has fallen to $m_1$. Some mass has "evaporated" and turned into other forms of energy, for example by alpha decay of Uranium-235.

Given that the conservation of momentum mandates that $m_0v_0=m_1v_1$ and that the mass has decreased, it seems like the velocity of the box had to have increased.

This seems strange because for an outside observer it looks like the black box has spontaneously accelerated without any external force acting on it. This would even allow for creating a simple, yet effective, rocket engine - just take some uranium onboard and see the rocket start to fly faster all by itself.

Comment: First note: you forgot the momentum of the alpha-particles | 
Second note: In relativity (which you should study) energy-momentum" is a 4-vector (or tensor), that takes into account the case where photons or high speed 'relativistic particles' are emitted | 
Third note: Oh, it's a homework problem and you forgot to study relativity ;-)

Answer (score 9):

These two statements are incompatible with each other

> an ideal box, which perfectly isolates the inside from the outside - no radiation escapes the box and the outer surface of the box does not change in any way

And

> the total mass of the box and the partially decayed lump has fallen to $m_1$

If nothing escapes the box, specifically is no energy or momentum leaves the box, then the mass of the box is constant regardless of what happens inside the box.

The mass of the box is given by $$m^2 c^2=E^2/c^2-p^2$$ so if the box is isolated then $E$ and $p$ are constant by the conservation of energy and momentum respectively. Therefore $m$ is also constant.

I suspect that the reason you believe that the mass decreases is because of the very common misunderstanding that $E=mc^2$ represents a “conversion” between mass and energy. This is an incorrect understanding because if $m$ is “converted” into $E$ then $m$ decreases and $E$ increases which would violate the conservation of energy.

Also, if scientists had wanted to write a formula stating that mass could be converted into energy it would be $\Delta E=-\Delta m c^2$. The form of $E=mc^2$ is intended to convey a relationship that holds at each instant of time, just like $F=ma$ is intended to hold at each instant of time. So the $E$ at rest at some instant in time is equal to $mc^2$ at that same instant of time.

Note that the famous $E =mc^2$ is a special case of the more general $m^2 c^2=E^2/c^2-p^2$ for $p=0$. In radioactive decay (in the center of momentum frame) a particle “splits” into two particles with equal and opposite momentum. Since the momentum is equal and opposite, the total $p$ is unchanged (it remains 0 in the center of momentum frame). Some of the rest energy is converted into kinetic energy, but by conservation of energy the total $E$ is unchanged. Therefore the total mass of the box is unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

You have to decide whether you want to model the box or not; on the left of your picture you don't assign it any mass, but on the right it scatters the alpha particles. Momentum conservation holds also for radioactive decay of course. You can model it as a mass in a box with a loaded spring that ejects a marble, same thing. Momentum of the combined system mass plus ejecta plus box is conserved.

Comment: I don’t believe the mass of the box-inside system is conserved. That’s because some mass is converted into binding energy.

Comment: @janekb04 But it doesn't work like that. Let's consider an extreme case. Let's say your ideal impervious box has a mass of 1 kg. You carefully put in 5kg of matter and 5 kg of antimatter and seal the box. The total mass of the system is 11 kg. When the matter and antimatter annihilate the total mass is still 11 kg.

Comment: @PM2Ring Where are these 10kg? Annihilation produces only photons, which do not have mass. If the box would still have 11kg, then these 10kg (of photons?) would gravitationally attract other objects. This seems very counterintuitive.

Comment: @janekb04 Sure, photons have zero (rest) mass, but they have energy, and all that energy is still in the box.

Comment: "This seems very counterintuitive".  So?  It doesn't have to match your intuition -- or mine.  It needs to match reality, and then _we_ need to pound on our intuition until _it_ also matches reality.

Comment: Photons do not have "rest mass", but they do have energy and it still bends spacetime. So yes, they do gravitationally attract other objects (in general relativity, unlike in Newtonian or even special relativistic mechanics.) The amount of attraction is so small as to be practically irrelevant and I'm not sure if we have ever even had the ability to directly measure it.

Comment: @TimWescott The model where "mass" is defined as rest mass has some very counterintuitive consequences. That free light is massless, while trapped light has mass is weird. However, the advocates of this model can point to different weirdnesses if you assume $E=mc^2$, giving free light mass. They *should* just get used to writing $m_0$ for rest mass, but that's too much of a burden, I guess.

Answer (score -2):

You may understand this easily using $E=mc^2$ and the old concept of relativistic mass. The mass doesn't decline for the simple reason that you've not allowed any energy to leak from the box. The mass is always simply $E/c^2$.

Dale, above, uses a different, revisionist definition of mass, but that just complicates problems of this sort.